# Same SPROC with different names performs differently when called from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have two identical stored procedures, but with different names. When I call Sproc A from C# I get a quicker overall response when compared to Sproc B. When I run each Sproc in SSMS and include the execution plan I get the very close to the same results. Any ideas as to what might cause this discrpency?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that and I see that they run at the same speed after recompiling. Unfortunately they are running at the slower of the two speeds. If I change the name of the SPROC to use the original faster one then the speed stays the same after the first run, but after the second run it speeds up again. ??

Comment: It's possible the data is still cached after the first run.

Comment: I promoted my comment to an answer. It was a little bit of a stab in the dark initially.

Comment: Any thoughts on how I might get back to my original faster speed? I am not able to achieve this speed with the newer named SPROC even though the SQL matches the previously named SPROC. I tried using the WITH RECOMPILE hint which made it somewhat faster, but still not as fast as the original one.

Comment: It's going to depend on the query plan that gets generated, and that's going to depend on the parameters that are passed initially. `WITH RECOMPILE` will help if the parameters being passed often require different query plans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you passing the same parameters? I believe the procs receive a query plan the first time they are compiled, and that plan is based on the parameters passed. So they may have different query plans depending on how they were initially called. As a test, run sp_recompile on them and make sure they both get called with the same parameters the first time so they get the same query plan.

Comment: Thanks for your help, as you were suggesting it seems that the issue here was parameter sniffing. After using a local variable for one of my parameters I was able to consistently get back the faster performance.